# Accepting Twitter friendship request using accept.json

Tags: c#, json, twitter

Has anyone successfully automated and accepted friendship request on their twitter account without the need to click the accept button manually?

I am trying to automatically accept friendship requests for my restricted twitter account.  I realize that the Twitter API call to */friendships/accept.json* is restricted and I keep getting a 401 unauthorized access error.

I have tried to obtain the post_authenticity_token value using various methods to then used it in the POST parameters sent to the accept.json request as mentioned in the following post:
[Twitter API: Allow accept request to follow authenticated user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271340/twitter-api-allow-accept-request-to-follow-authenticated-user)

but it keeps failing every time.  Any insight or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are authenticating yourself beforehand right?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `post_authenticity_token`. You are essentially screen scraping which is fragile, against their TOS, and not working. Instead use the standard [OAuth authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) method their API officially supports.